# Capistrano destroys ssh public key authorisation

Tags: ssh, capistrano, public-key

I am quite out of my depths with a problem that I have faced with two different ssh-users on two different servers where I deploy to with Capistrano. I am sure I am not the only one to have come across this:

1. I set up an ssh-connection from the command line with passwordless authentication, using my public key, that is known to the remote server. This works: I can log into the remote system.
2. I execute »cap deploy:setup«. Surprisingly, I have to enter the password of the ssh-user, and from then I have to enter the password again each time I log into the server via ssh on the command line. The public key is not accepted any more, as shown by the output produced by ssh's -v option:

_

```
shell$ ssh -vp 5222 my_ssh_user@my-remote-host.de
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my-remote-host.de [1.2.3.4] port 5222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/martin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/martin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/martin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/martin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[my-remote-host.de]:5222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/martin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/martin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
my_ssh_user@my-remote-host.de's password: <here I enter my password>
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to my-remote-host.de ([1.2.3.4]:5222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
Linux ve2003 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5.028stab085.5 #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 15:42:34 MSD 2011 x86_64

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To access official Ubuntu documentation, please visit:
http://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Fri Sep 23 13:05:55 2011 from
```

I am using Mac OS Lion locally and Ubuntu on the remote side. My Capistrano is extended by the multistage-extension. I have set

```
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
```

and it works for the passwordless pulling of the git repository on the remote side.

How can I prevent Capistrano to scrumble up my SSH settings and make it use public key auth again?

Greatly appreciate any help!

EDIT: The problem is Server-side: I just found out that I cannot use other systems to passwordless log into my remote system. How can I know what is wrong with the server?

Comment: apparently cap has trashed .ssh/authorized_keys on the server, either content or modes.

Comment: authorized_keys is still readable for all and contains my public key. Just talked to the sysadmin. He said there maybe configuration issues with the jail he has set up for the SSH user. So we may check on that first. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: ssh publickey login will not work if the .ssh directory and the authorized_keys file are group or world readable.